# Android Tabs in Bar

Tags: java, android

I am doing this course:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText
And I am trying to create tabs on my app.
Used the xml code that they gave but don't know what to do now.

Comment: The tab navigation mode is deprecated from api 21: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS

I propose to use other navigation type in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you specified was for Styling the Action Bar not for creating the tabs! If you are looking for creating tabs in android go through the simple tutorial here,

[Android Fragment Tabs Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragment-tabs-example/)

If you are interested on developing tabs in action bar, you may check this too,

[Android Action Bar (ActionBar) Tab navigation](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html)